# Search database based on name with multiple returns. django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hello guys am building a search tool for postgres in django and am getting a lot of errors my output is in this way.
<QuerySet [<Bindll: HIV-1 protease>, <Bindll: HIV-1 protease>, <Bindll: HIV-1 protease>

my code is

```
#Search resuts page.

{% extends 'Search/base.html' %}
{%block content  %}
        <center>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
<h1>{% if ChemSearched %}
        {{ChemSearched}}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        {% for Bindll in tarname %}
                        {{tarname}}<br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </h1></strong>
                    {% else %}
                    <strong>No Entry</strong>
                    {% endif %}           
                    Copyright (c) 
            </center>
{% endblock %}
```

My database name in Bindll.

```
#Views.py page
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Bindll
def search_result(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ChemSearched = request.POST.get('ChemSearched')
        tarname = Bindll.objects.filter(targetnameassignedbycuratorordatasource__contains=ChemSearched)

        return render(request, 'Search/search_result.html',
            {'ChemSearched':ChemSearched,'tarname':tarname})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Search/search_result.html',{})
```

using Postgresql and gitbash if related.
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `forloop` you need to access the iterated variable not the actual context

```
{% for Bindll in tarname %}
  {{Bindll}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```